# Extract substring from file path in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, osx-snow-leopard

I need to extract substring from list of file paths. Paths are like "\rootfolder\subfolder". Need extract substring as "rootfolder" ( between 2nd backslash and 3rd backslash.

```
select SUBSTR('\\rootfolder\subfolder\', 3, (REGEXP_INSTR('\\rootfolder\subfolder\','\', 1, 3) - 3)) from table;
```

But this expression didn't give right result in Snowflake. problem is with backslash character.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html):

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART($$\\rootfolder\subfolder\$$, $$\$$, 3);
--
SELECT SPLIT_PART('\\\\rootfolder\\subfolder\\', '\\', 3);
```

Output:

[image]

[Dollar quoting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#dollar-quoted-string-constants) was used to avoid doubling `\`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @lukasz. I have tried SELECT SPLIT_PART('\\rootfolder\subfolder\', '\', 2) , but single backslash is not accepting in snowflake. Syntax error "unexpected '\'"

Comment: @JanakiRam Please check the code either using dollar quoting or second versiona as both work fine